# Axiomatizing higher-dimensional geometries

Tags: geometry, axioms, noneuclidean-geometry, axiomatic-geometry

While there are various axiom systems for two and three-dimensional geometries (Hilbert, etc.), it seems not at all clear that this axiomatic approach generalizes well to more than three dimensions. Hilbert's original *Foundations of Geometry* is explicitly three-dimensional. Tarski's axiom system appears generalizable to arbitrary dimensions, but seems rarely used and also (per my cursory understanding) somewhat limited (by being strictly first-order, apparently it can't even prove all the theorems from Euclid's *Elements*).

So my question is basically: Is formal axiomatization, in actual practice, particularly important (or at all useful) for geometry of higher (> 3) dimensions (whether euclidean or non-euclidean)?

- My *guess* would be "no", i.e. that the preferred approach would be to skip the formal axiomatization and just describe things in terms of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, distance metric, etc. (this is the approach taken in Baby Rudin section 1.36 defining k-dimensional "Euclidean k-space" -- Rudin makes no mention there of any geometric axioms)

Comment: I have not seen anyone use an axiomatization like this to do anything. In practice people talk about Riemannian manifolds.

Comment: That does lead me to wonder why books like those by Robin Hartshorne and Marvin Greenberg focus on this axiomatic approach. I guess because it was historically the way that people first started thinking about non-euclidean geometries (and thinking more rigorously about what geometry can/should be)?

Comment: Frequently, people write books because they teach the material in their classes. My guess is that this applies to the books by Hartshorne and by Greenberg. I confirm that the linear algebra approach is the favorite axiomatization of Euclidean geometry in dimensions $\ge 3$. For hyperbolic geometry, it is either linear algebra (the Lorentzian model) or Riemannian geometry.

Comment: Tarski’s axiom system can also be used with a second order continuity axiom such as Dedekind cuts and then you get $R^n$ as  a model so there is no restriction. If one wants to study neutral geometry in arbitrary dimension I think the synthetic approach is the only one possible.

Comment: @JulienNarboux : Interesting. When you refer to the synthetic approach in arbitrary number of dimensions, does that necessarily mean the Tarski axiom system? (Tarski’s is the only axiomatization I know of that really accommodates arbitrary number dimensions, but maybe there are others?)

Comment: Yes there are others. See the works of Pambuccian and Bachmann for example.

Comment: @JulienNarboux : I see. So then “the synthetic approach” means an approach based on one of these axiom systems?